# Launch app from background service

Tags: ios, service, background, accelerometer, ios7

I've developed Android app which has a background service in the sleep mode. This service works with accelerometer data and can launch the app from the sleep mode over the lock screen.

Is it possible to make the same on iOS? 

I mean:

1. Create a service which can work in background with accelerometer data.
2. Service can launch the app when the phone is in the sleep mode over lock screen. (without unlocking)

If I'm not mistaken it must be possible on iOS7, isn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that iOS 7 is still under NDA. For answers on iOS7, I suggest going to the Apple Developer Forums.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Yes** – Apple publicly stated background processing at WWDC keynote and it can be done to a degree on iOS6
2. **No** – Apple will 'probably' never allow an app to be opened without the user instigating it and certainly not over the lock screen.

You could use [Push / Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) which do appear on the lock screen to try and entice a user at a specific time to launch the app but no guarantees.